# How to reproduce some events in a calendar in another

Tags: workflow, calendar, content-query-web-part

I have a calendar in site A, which includes a yes/no field. I want events with 'yes' to appear in a calendar on site B. Things I have tried:
- adding the calendar to site B, with a 'yes' only view. Can't be done because the calendar does not appear as an app I can add on site B, only on site A
- content query web part, pulling 'yes' events from calendar on site A to CQWP in site B. This works, except it looks like a list instead of a calendar view
- setting up a workflow to duplicate items from the calendar on site A to one I create in site B. Can't seem to do this, as I am using sharepoint online and the 'Copy List Item' option is not available. Also, I want it to update if anyone changes items on the calendar in site A.
Would really appreciate any guidance, non-coding for preference, I'm very much focused on the user rather than the developer end of sharepoint!

Comment: instead of using "copy list item" in a workflow, try "create item in" then choose calendar B and set up what you would like each field to contain.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using SPOnlie, it would be great to use [Microsoft FLow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/) here some solutions may help you to achieve goals:

create 2 flows the first one triggs whenever an item create on Calendar A, and the second one triggs when an item on Calendar A modified

[image]

[image]